# Syntax for if clause with an inline variable in modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, syntax

In the "Calculate Value" tool I am trying to slice the inline variable (%Name%) with another variable (A) that will be a result of the length of the %Name% variable.  For example if
%Name% = 11 then I would like A = 8, else I would like A = 9.

"%Name%"[:A]

- What should be the syntax of the expression and the code block?
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calculate Value Documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm)

Expression:

```
fn("%Name%")
```

Code Block:

```
def fn(name):
    if len(name) is 11:
        A = 8
    else:
        A = 9

    return name[:A]
```

[image]

Comment: here is an example (with completely incorrect syntax) on what I am trying to do:      
 if len(%Name%) = 11 then
 %A% = 8
 else 
%A% = 9
end if

Comment: Updated answer. Does this answer your question? You want to slice the input string based on its length?